# NumPy stride tricks to get non-overlapping 3D cubes from larger 3D cube array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I use numpy stride tricks to get non-overlapping, equal-sized 3D blocks of arrays from a larger 3D array? I would like to take an array of shape `(256, 256, 256)` and reshape it to `(8, 128, 128, 128)`, where each sub-array in the first axis is a cube from the larger array. In other words, I would like to stack the 8 equal-sized, non-overlapping cubes that make up the larger cube in the first axis. Simply reshaping the array to this new shape does not give this result.

I am able to achieve this with Scikit-Image's implementation ([`skimage.util.view_as_blocks`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/1f56de9595d7db2aa7107e9ec5211d971a1420c6/skimage/util/shape.py#L10)) and a subsequent reshape. Please see the code below. Note that the reshape makes a copy of the array.

Is it possible to achieve this with strides and without the reshape?

```
import numpy as np

# Create a 3D (cube) array with each side length 256.
len_ = 256
foo = np.arange(len_**3).reshape((len_, len_, len_))
foo = np.ascontiguousarray(foo)

# View blocks of shape (128, 128, 128).
block_shape = (len_ // 2,) * 3

# Bits taken from `skimage.utils.view_as_blocks`
new_shape = tuple(foo.shape // np.array(block_shape)) + block_shape
new_strides = tuple(foo.strides * np.array(block_shape)) + foo.strides
blocks =  np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(foo, shape=new_shape, strides=new_strides)
print("shape", blocks.shape)
print("strides", blocks.strides)
# shape (2, 2, 2, 128, 128, 128)
# strides (67108864, 262144, 1024, 524288, 2048, 8)

blocks_reshaped = blocks.reshape((-1, *block_shape))
print("shape", blocks_reshaped.shape)
print("strides", blocks_reshaped.strides)

# shape (8, 128, 128, 128)
# strides (16777216, 131072, 1024, 8)

blocks_reshaped.base is blocks  # False
```

Comment: Do you need stride tricks? It would seem `foo.reshape((8, 128, 128, 128))
` gives you what you want.

Comment: Agree with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ... why do you not want to reshape?

Comment: If you are looking for an output of shape `(8, 128, 128, 128)`,which would be a view of the input, that's not possible.

Comment: @Alex and @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - `foo.reshape((8, 128, 128, 128))` gives the correct shape but the incorrect representation of the data. I am working with 3-D magnetic resonance volumes and the reshape corrupts the volumes. Thanks @Divakar. That's the answer to my question.

Comment: A shorter way with permuting axes would be : `shp = a.shape; shp1 = np.hstack([(i//2,2) for i in shp]); shp2 = [8,] + [i//2 for i in shp]; out = a.reshape(shp1).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape(shp2)`. You can skip that last `.reshape(shp2)` for a view though.

Comment: What are you going to do with the result?  Why can't you use the result of `skimage.util.view_as_blocks`?  That is, why do you need to organize the blocks in one dimension rather than three?

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. @Warren Weckesser - I am feeding the array into a 3D convolutional neural network. The first dimension is the batch. Each `(128, 128, 128`) array in the batch is a volume that I train/test on.